# Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 22

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

i'm trying to change the preg_match check from url checking and i'm getting this error

> Blockquote
>   preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 22

this is the code:

```
preg_match_all('#\b(' . $allWordsFromProduct . ')\b#ui', $name, $matches);
```

Comment: What is inside `$allWordsFromProduct`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May `$allWordsFromProduct` contains special regex character. You can try:

```
 $allWordsFromProduct = preg_quote($allWordsFromProduct , '#');
 preg_match_all('#\b(' . $allWordsFromProduct . ')\b#ui', $name, $matches);
```

This will escape them.